# Is $S^2/\sim$ a $CW$-complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the equivalence relation on $S^2$ define by $x\sim -x$ if $x\in S^{1}$ (we are supposed to see $S^1\hookrightarrow S^2$ as the equator) and $x\sim x$ otherwise. I have some questions concerning the quotient space $S^2/\sim$:

1. Is $S^2/\sim$ a $CW$-complex?
2. If so, what is the cell structure on it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert but I think it is a CW-complex. You will have one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and two $2$-cells. The function used to glue the two $2$-cells to $S^1$ is the same and it is $z\mapsto z^2$ (if you think $S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$).

I see this very similar to the CW-structure on $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: In fact, it is $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with an extra $2$-cell attached.

Comment: can you explain a bit more @DanielRobert-Nicoud?

Comment: If you do this construction but only with the north hemisphere you get the projective plane. Now, you can add the south hemisphere to get your space.